# Selecting points above/under lines

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,2), columns=list('AB'))
```

plot data

```
plt.scatter(x=df.A, y=df.B)

x = plt.axhline(y=0.4,c='k')
y = plt.axvline(x=0.4,c='k')
plt.plot([0.2, 0.3], [0, 0.4], c='k')
```

I want to select the points in the green areas(see graph below). The points in the second quadrant were easy to select but not the points in the green area in the third quadrant.

This is how i selected points in the second quadrants:

```
df[( df['A'] < 0.4) & (df['B'] > 0.4)]
```

after this I got stuck.

Considering the conditions might get complex, like dealing with curved lines etc. What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Open for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Is the `[0.2, 0.3], [0, 0.4]` line function determined? And how would you like to solve the problem, i.e. via math function or apply a classifier?

Comment: I would try something like df[( df['A'] < 0.4) & ((df['B'] > 0.4) | df['B'] < f(['A']))], whereas f(['A']) would be the function defining that curve you have in the third quadrant. I don't currently have a Python IDE at hand - I'll provide a proper answer once I do.

Comment: @knh190 that's not a function but to visualise what I want to do. I prefer to see both methods if possible, mathematically and by applying a classifier.

Comment: @sekky thank you. Looking forward to your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I promised a solution, here is one without using functools:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,2), columns=list('AB'))
plt.scatter(x=df.A, y=df.B)

x = plt.axhline(y=0.4,c='k')
y = plt.axvline(x=0.4,c='k')
plt.plot([0.2, 0.3], [0, 0.4], c='k')

# the next line is the one selecting all datapoints within 
sub_df = df[(( df['A'] < 0.4) & (df['B'] > 0.4)) | (df['B'] < 0.4) & (df['A'] < (0.2 + 0.25*df['B']))]
plt.scatter(sub_df['A'], sub_df['B'], marker='x', color='red')

plt.xlabel('A')
plt.ylabel('B')

plt.show()
```

The clause `df['A'] < (0.2 + 0.25*df['B'])` just describes a linear function. You can substitute this for anything else (for example an exponential function).

The resulting plot from the above code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, functools worked as well but this is simpler and easy to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you can use functools:

```
import numpy as np
import functools

cr1 = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [df.B < 0.4, df.A < 0.2])
cr2 = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [df.B < 0.4, df.A > 0.2, df.B > (df.A-0.2)*4])
df_filtered = df[functools.reduce(np.logical_or, [cr1,cr2])]
```

Comment: Thank you, but i had to change these equations to get the desired results:   'cr1 = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [ df.A<0.4, df.B>0.4])
  cr2 = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [ df.B < 0.4, df.B > (df.A-0.2)*4])'